# Работа с исключениями. Не срабатывает блок finally

Tags: c#

Есть такой код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try { Console.WriteLine(1); throw new Exception(); }
    catch(DivideByZeroException) { Console.WriteLine(2); }
    finally { Console.WriteLine(3); }
    Console.WriteLine(4);
}
```

Как видно, что здесь генерируется некоторое исключение, которое НЕ ловится блоком `catch`, по идее должен сработать `finally` - так как он срабатывает всегда не зависимо от того было исключение или нет. Но почему-то у меня он не выводит цифру 3 на консоль. Почему это может быть ?

Comment: Кстати, что-то не воспроизводится: https://ideone.com/8GtTMR

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Это, как ни странно, ожидаемое поведение. [Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx) гласит:

> Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed to be run. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. That, in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up.

то есть

> В случае пойманного исключения, блок `finally` гарантированно выполнится. Однако в случае если исключение не поймано, выполнение блока `finally` зависит от того, как именно была вызвана операция размотки стека. Это, в свою очередь, зависит от того, как настроен ваш компьютер.

В вашем случае как раз исключение не ловится, так что код в `finally` имеет право потеряться.

---

Ещё несколько случаев, когда блок `finally` не выполнится:

- Было брошено достаточно «вредное» исключение:

  - [`StackOverflowException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx)
  - исключения, свидетельствующие о повреждении состояния CLR, например, [`AccessViolationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx), могут приводить к пропуску `catch` и `finally`.
- Код блока `catch` (или одного из фильтров исключений) может никогда не завершиться, например, войти в бесконечный цикл или бесконечное ожидание (deadlock).
- Внутри блока `catch` (или одного из фильтров исключений) программа может быть завершена с использованием [`Environment.FailFast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100(v=vs.110).aspx) или [`Environment.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Процесс может быть завершён операционной системой или другим процессом при помощи WinAPI-функции [`TerminateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx). Ну или вашим же процессом тоже.
- Операционная система может перестать функционировать. Например, питание компьютера может отключиться за время выполнения `catch`.

---

Дополнение: *Кажется*, можно заставить выполниться блоки `finally` в случае необработанного исключения, используя дополнительный блок `try`/`catch`/`throw` вокруг всей программы:

```
try
{
    try { Console.WriteLine(1); throw new Exception(); }
    catch (DivideByZeroException) { Console.WriteLine(2); }
    finally { Console.WriteLine(3); }
    Console.WriteLine(4);
}
catch { throw; }
```

(Но я покамест не могу найти подтверждение этому в документации.)

---

За поведение размотки стека в отладчике отвечает вот эта настройка:

[image: настройки отладки]

Comment: Спасибо ! Заметил, что если успеть нажать "Отмена" в окне "Прекращена работа программы" - тогда блок финали выводится, если дождаться кнопки "Закрыть программу", тогда нет.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey: Ага, это связано с тем, что делает с исключением _отладчик_.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, если исключение не покинет `main`, то `finally` должен выполниться, если не ошибаюсь. Поэтому есть смысл перехватывать все исключения в `main`, а потом делать `throw;`

Comment: @VladD на самом деле все просто. Блок finally выполняется всегда, за исключением ситуаций когда программа убивается раньше.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, вопрос в том, когда программа убивается _быстро_, а когда ещё мучается. Например, `return` из `Main` не убивает программу, `Application.Exit` в WPF тоже не убивает программу. Ну или ещё возможен случай бесконечного цикла, да.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: И гляньте ещё дополнение в ответе, оно неочевидно. (Например, если catch/throw заменить на finally, эффекта не будет.)

Comment: @VladD оно очевидно тем кто знает как работает SEH.

Comment: @VladD кстати, в документации явно же написано: *"В случае пойманного исключения, блок finally гарантированно выполнится"*. К моменту, когда выполняется внешний throw - исключение уже поймано, а значит и блок finally должен был выполниться... Тут главное чтобы оптимизатор не заоптимизировал пустой блок.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Для этого нужно, чтобы конструкция catch/throw подпадала под категорию «исключение поймано». Потому что поймано-то оно поймано, но потом снова выброшено. Это и есть не очевидный для меня момент.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, оптимизатор по идее не имеет право менять семантику однопоточной программы, такшта...

Comment: Кстати, что-то не воспроизводится: https://ideone.com/8GtTMR

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, документация не гарантирует же ничего. «the associated finally block is guaranteed to be run», значит, может пробежит, а может нет.