# Что-то не так с блоком finally

Tags: c#

Блок finally должен вывести пару сообщений перед тем, как программа закроется,однако сообщения не выходят

```
        string name = default(string);
        try
        {
            WriteLine("\tРегистрация нового пользователя");
            Write("Имя: ");
            name = ReadLine();
            throw new Exception();
        }
        finally
        {
            WriteLine("Уууупс, произошла ошибка");
            WriteLine("Очистка данных регистрации...");
            name = default(string);
        }
```

Comment: А если поймать исключение снаружи?

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564015/10105

Comment: @VladD программу писал в рамках своего обучения,смысл в том,что бы вышли сообщения якобы об ошибке.В книге есть пример схожий, и блок finally там выполняется,наверное..

Comment: Спасибо, за информацию

Comment: Ага, тогда можно закрывать как дубликат?

Comment: @VladD весьма похоже на то.

Comment: @VladD незнаю значения слова дубликат, но все работает после установленной галочки, выводится сообщение и остальное)

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик: Ну, смысл в том, что ваш вопрос аналогичен тому, другому вопросу :)