# c# try catch Вложенные

Tags: c#

Как происходит обработка блока finally, если идет конструкция

```
try {
   try { }
   catch {}
   finally {}
}
catch {}
finally {}
```

Сработает тот и тот блок или же?

Answer (score 5):

Должны отработать оба `finally`, т.к. блок `finally` Отрабатывает всегда (см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)), если исключение поймано. Если не поймано, то здесь уже нет гарантий выполнения.

Comment: Но если очень постараться, то не всегда)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, и [ссылочку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564015/186999) в подкрепление :)

Comment: @Grundy, чо-то совсем подозрительно о_О

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try{
        try{
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch{
            Console.WriteLine("Inner catch");
        }
        finally{
            Console.WriteLine("Inner finally");
        }
    }
    catch{
        Console.WriteLine("Outer catch");
    }
    finally{
        Console.WriteLine("Outer finally");
    }
}
```

Результат:

> Inner catch
>
> Inner finally
>
> Outer finally

Comment: Добавьте в вложенный catch, проброс исключения и внешний catch, тоже сработает.